# Writing javascript functions with dynamically created data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to have a javascript/jquery function that references dynamically created html.

Essentially I have a form that is created dynamically through `$('#list').append('an html form')`.  And then a function that looks something like:

```
function add_repo(id){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/add_project/',
        datatype:'json',
        data:{'name': $('#'+id).value()},
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
    })
}
```

where id is a dynamically created identifier for each form created by the jquery `append` function.

But `add_repo()` causes an error in the javascript as the jquery id identifiers don't exist initially.  How should situations like this be handled?

Comment: How are you calling it `onload`?

Comment: both functions are currently in the head. moving the add_repo to the body solved the problem... that was easy enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function that is called at runtime:

```
function add_repo(id){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/add_project/',
        datatype:'json',
        data:{'name': function() {
           return($('#'+id).value());
         }},
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
data:{'name': $('#'+id).value()},
```

to

```
   data:{'name': $('#'+id).val()},
```